# Windows Terminal doesn't recognize a script function

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal, powershell-5.1

I've recently discovered the `Windows Terminal` and wanted to give it a try. However, it doesn't seem to work the same as the original PowerShell Console. When I try to call a script function in it like `. .\Func-Test.ps1; My-Func -test abc` it says:

> My-Func : The term 'My-Func' is not recognized as the name of a
> cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
> of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is
> correct and try again. At line:1 char:15
>
> - . .\Func-Test; My-Func -test abc
> - ```
>             ~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (My-Func:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Doing the same in the classic PowerShell Console works without any issues. Both consoles use the same `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` which is `5.1.19041.1682`.

Am I using the Windows Terminal incorrectly or isn't this supposed to work in it (yet)?

Comment: Works for me when hosting Windows PowerShell 5.1 in Windows Terminal, both with `. .\Func-Test; ...` and `. .\Func-Test.ps1; ...`. Are you sure `.\Func-Test.ps1` contains a valid function definition for `My-Func`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I'm positive about it. I first tried it in Windows Terminal and then copy/pasted everything including paths etc into PS-Console and it worked there.

Comment: What paths? The code you've posted and the error message suggests you're importing `Func-Test.ps1` from the current directory...

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen ehm, sorry I meant the path where my script is the `cd c:\some\path` so it's the current working directory for `.`. But now that you confim it's working for you I tried one more thing, this is setting the execution policy in Windows Terminal an that fixed it :\ It looks like it has its own _environment_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *fixed* it by executing as Administrator this command in the Windows Terminal. Strangely the PowerShell Console already showed `RemoteSigned`. Apparently they use different environments.

> ```
> Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
> ```